# What css position: or overflow do you use for smaller screens/minimized screens?

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning

What is the correct way to position elements in css for smaller screens/minimizing?
If I don't use overflow, my site leaks onto whitespace and if i use overflow:hidden it's obviously no longer visible. I have most things positioned relatively to the document. Which overflow method or position do I use to let the user scroll to see the rest of the page if its minimized?

css:

```
    body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}

#headr {
        background-image:url(../images/top%20bg.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        height:400px;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        z-index:-100;
        overflow:hidden;
}

#lgo {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:33%;
    margin-top:80px;
    min-height:inherit;
}

#nav {
    background-image:url(../images/nav%20bar.png);
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:99px;
}

#listone {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:570px;
    top:25px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.navlist {
    display:inline;
    font-size:33px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:georgia;
    position:static;
}

#searchb {
    background-image:url(../images/search.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:1350px;
    margin-top:-80px;
}

#searchb form {
    display:inline;
}
#searchbar {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:60px;
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    outline:none;
    font-size:24px;
}

.searchsubmit {
    border:0px;
    background-color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:33px;
    left:200px;
    width:30px;
    height:40px;
}
```

html:

```
    <div id="nav">
<ul id="listone">
<li class="navlist">Home</li>
<li class="navlist">Portfolio</li>
<li class="navlist">Prices</li>
<li class="navlist">Contact</li>

</ul>
<div id="searchb">
<form>
<input type="text" id="searchbar" placeholder="Search">
<input type="image" class="searchsubmit" src="images/searchicon.png" value="">
</form></div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="headr">
<img src="images/head logo.png" id="lgo">
</div>
```

the search bar which are the last 3 ID's in the css, is the object that's too big for the screen. you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Pp4.png

Answer (score 2):

Set it to `overflow:auto;` to make it flow accordingly.

Comment: that's what i want, however when i scroll out its just showing white space. Like here:  http://i.imgur.com/q4DasQ7.png The darker blue and lighter blue are two different div's and their width is set to 100%

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q4L64/ - This is what I can see from your code. - @joe Your work scenario like the snapshot is not generated. Make your own fiddle and provide with your work scenario to further debug the issue.

Comment: minimized: http://i.imgur.com/CfCrmub.png, the white space: http://i.imgur.com/p8dwiP9.png

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/q4L64/ i'd have to upload all the images for you to see what it actually looks like. but the screen shots i've linked show it